# How does perf use the offcore events?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, perf, intel-pmu

Some built-in `perf` events are mapped to offcore events. For example, `LLC-loads` and `LLC-load-misses` are mapped to `OFFCORE_RESPONSE.` events. This can be easily determined as discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170960/hardware-cache-events-and-perf). However, these offcore events require writing certain values to certain MSR registers to actually specify a particular event. `perf` seems to be using an array called something like [snb_hw_cache_extra_regs](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.3/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L577) to specify what values to write to which MSR registers. I would like to know how this array is used. Basically I want to know how to determine the specific offcore event that a `perf` event is mapped to by looking at the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array of the offcore PM MSRs is stored [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.3/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L220) for SnB, other architectures are close.
The macro `INTEL_UEVENT_EXTRA_REG` is [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.3/source/arch/x86/events/perf_event.h#L452) and it just sets the `msr` to the second parameter, the `config_mask` to `0x000000FFULL` and the `valid_mask` to the third parameter (the first being the event to program the the associated ordinary PMR with).

The values of the `snb_hw_cache_extra_regs` is just what it's going to be written in the selected PM MSR<sup>1</sup>.
This array is looked up [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.3/source/arch/x86/events/core.c#L302) and used 
[here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.3/source/arch/x86/events/core.c#L135) to select the first PM MSR matching, where the `config` arg comes from the array [`hw_cache_event_ids`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16.3/source/arch/x86/events/intel/core.c#L623).

So it's basically a loop testing a couple of bitmasks until a compatible PM MSR is found, I think you can just skip that and look at the values stored in the `snb_hw_cache_extra_regs` array.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Since the macro defined to make the values in `snb_hw_cache_extra_regs` are never reused in source and the values maps directly to the MSR layout documented in the Intel manuals, I didn't bother verifying this statement.